# Can I change the type of args from graphql's resolver to id?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typeorm

I would like to change the type from graphql's ID type in the query. Is it possible?

id: number ==> id: ID

```js
@Resolver()
export class LocationResolver {
    constructor(private readonly locationService: LocationService) {}

    @Query(() => Location_Group)
    async locationGroup(@Args('id') id: number): Promise<Location_Group> {
        return await this.locationService.getLocationGroup(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it. @Args('id', { type: () => ID }) id: number

Comment: Can you post the answer to help others in the future? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my answer:

```js
@Query(() => Location)
async location(
    @Args('id', { type: () => ID }) id: number
): Promise<Location> {
    return await this.locationService.findLocation(id);
}
```